# C# .NET Controls for docked tool windows?

Tags: c#, controls, widget

I was using Qt with C++ to develop my GUI applications, but I have recently switched to try out C# .NET as it is much easier to do what I need to.

I was wondering what controls I need to be using for a few things and if they exist for C# .NET or if I need to do something custom/special.

[image: example screenshot showing docked tool windows]

If you look in that screenshot, I want to do something similar to how they have each tool window grouped into its own docking area with the option of closing it or breaking it out of the layout so it can be dragged. I am talking about the tool windows titled "Groups", "Resources", "Tools", etc.

I also want to make these tool windows stay in the same place when the main window is resized. Qt has spring like widgets that will let you create a UI that keeps its shape when the window is resized. Does anything like this exist in C# .NET?

Comment: Do you need it for WinForms or for WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divelements has some good components for this type of thing.  Been a while since I used them but its dock controls were pretty easy to get up and running with and are very feature rich.

http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sanddock/

They've got WPF and WinForms versions.